# How to unpack the former values of the following nested list of tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list-comprehension

```
>>>lis = df['col'].values.tolist()    

>>>lis = [[(('A', 'WE'), ('1,21', 'rr'), ('io', 'mp'))], 
     [(('B', 'WE'), ('5', 'rr'), ('io', 'mp'))],
     [(('A', 'WE'), ('3', 'rr'), ('io', 'mp')),
      (('C', 'WE'), ('0', 'rr'), ('io', 'mp'))],
     ....
     [(('D', 'WE'), ('6', 'rr'), ('io', 'mp'))],
     [(('A', 'WE'), ('9.0', 'rr'), ('io', 'mp'))]]
```

How to take only the firsts elements of each tuple and reformat it into:

```
 [[A, 1,21, io],
 [B, 5, io],
 [A, 3, io],
 [C, 0, io],
 ....
 [D, 6, io],
 [A, 9.0', io]]
```

I all ready tried to:

```
[' '.join(map(str,lis[0][0])) for x in lis]
```

and

```
[' '.join(map(str,lis[0][:1])) for x in lis]
```

and

```
' '.join(map(str, lis))
```

and

```
new_lis, _ = zip(*lis[0][0])    
return ' '.join(new_lis)
```

**UPDATE**

the pandas column looks like this:

```
   Col
0 [(('A', 'WE'), ('1,21', 'rr'), ('io', 'mp'))] 
1 [(('B', 'WE'), ('5', 'rr'), ('io', 'mp'))]
2 [(('A', 'WE'), ('3', 'rr'), ('io', 'mp'))
3 [(('C', 'WE'), ('0', 'rr'), ('io', 'mp'))]
   ....
n   [(('D', 'WE'), ('6', 'rr'), ('io', 'mp'))]
n-1 [(('A', 'WE'), ('9.0', 'rr'), ('io', 'mp'))]
```

Comment: what do you want it to look like when you are done?

Comment: As the example, just taking the first values separated by commas @EmettSpeer

Comment: Can you post what `df['col']` looks like?  There should be an easier way to extract this with pandas.

Comment: if you are just trying to make it into a single string `''.join(map(str, map(str, x)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
new_list = [[nested[0] for nested in sub_l] for l in lis for sub_l in l]
print(new_list)
[['A', '1,21', 'io'],
 ['B', '5', 'io'],
 ['A', '3', 'io'],
 ['C', '0', 'io'],
 ['D', '6', 'io'],
 ['A', '9.0', 'io']]
```

It's not very readable, but it make what you want.

**UPDATE**
If you want to have a list of strings you can use this code:

```
[",".join(nested[0] for nested in sub_l) for l in lis for sub_l in l]
```

Comment: This one actually worked. However, I can't do a  `'  '.join(new_list)` to remove the square parenthesis... How can I drop them?.

Comment: @tumbleweed I added to the answer

Answer (score 3):

```
lis = [[(('A', 'WE'), ('1,21', 'rr'), ('io', 'mp'))], 
     [(('B', 'WE'), ('5', 'rr'), ('io', 'mp'))],
     [(('A', 'WE'), ('3', 'rr'), ('io', 'mp')),
      (('C', 'WE'), ('0', 'rr'), ('io', 'mp'))],
     [(('D', 'WE'), ('6', 'rr'), ('io', 'mp'))],
     [(('A', 'WE'), ('9.0', 'rr'), ('io', 'mp'))]]

print [list(next(zip(*tup))) for subl in lis for tup in subl ]
```

Output:

```
[['A', '1,21', 'io'],
 ['B', '5', 'io'],
 ['A', '3', 'io'],
 ['C', '0', 'io'],
 ['D', '6', 'io'],
 ['A', '9.0', 'io']]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!... However I am getting the first letter and the second letter of each tuple: for  `('A', 'WE'), ('1,21', 'rr'), ('io', 'mp')` I got: `('A', W')`

Comment: @tumbleweed Ok try now.

Comment: Thanks!... But I got the same issue!

Comment: consider root's solution then. Next time provide `df.head()` in your question for quick solutions.

Comment: instead of `list(list(iterator)[0])` use `list(next(iterator))`

Comment: this method misses ['C', '0', 'io']